# Bash script produces error using if condition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with `if` in bash script. I've written the following if condition but it produces an error:

```
if [[ "$capacity" != *10 && "$capacity" != *20  ]] || [[ "$capacity" != *80 && "$capacity" != *100 ]]; then
```

Simply, I want to compare (two values not equals to) || (two values not equals to) condition using or operator

Comment: What are those `*` doing there?

Comment: Do we have to guess what the error is, or will you tell us?

Comment: it checks if $capacity ends with .10 , it works if I write only the first section like this -> if [[ "$capacity" != *10 && "$capacity" != *20  ]]; then

Comment: but if I add the or operator and next section it gives me an error

Comment: It only writes "expression error" on line where is my if , nothing else

Comment: @thatotherguy  no, problem is with OR operator and checking using that two conditions in seperate [] brackets

Comment: @thatotherguy look on my question and example

Comment: The code you show runs without an error for me.  Are you certain you are using bash and not sh?

Comment: I use #!/bin/sh

Comment: So why did you tag it with `bash`?

Comment: Can you please give an value for `capacity` where you expect the condition to be FALSE?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not bash. They're different shells implementing different languages. (Even when `/bin/sh` is a link to the bash executable, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode when run under that name).

Comment: You know that condition is a tautology (always true), right?

Answer (score 1):

I took your line and added enough additional lines to make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#!/bin/bash
capacity=55

if [[ "$capacity" != *10 && "$capacity" != *20  ]] || [[ "$capacity" != *80 && "$capacity" != *100 ]]; then
  echo "match"
fi
```

Then I ran it like this:

```
$ chmod +x ./myscript
$ ./myscript
match
```

It wrote "match", exactly as I expected.

Will you please do the same thing?

1. Add enough lines so that I can run your code on my machine
2. Show how you run it and what it outputs
3. Explain why this is different from what you expected

Comment: I saved it as script.sh and then I run it as ./script.sh

Comment: @jore The example you posted has no `fi` so this is indeed an error. You need a body for your `if` statement and a `fi` to terminate it

Comment: I pasted here only the part of my code without fi, i have it

Comment: @jore StackOverflow expects you to write a complete question that contains all the details needed to answer it. You have asked an incomplete question that is missing important information. Please improve your question. Click "edit" and add the missing information.